# jQuery unload(): Syntax error after updating a Cookie - how to find the cause?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

**Solution below: Edit #2**

I've a HTML-list the user is able to sort. I don't want to save the data after every drag/drop action, so I save the data on unload: in a cookie and database. Thats working, but:

After saving the data the list is hidden and I get a "syntax error" in this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It's strange because everything works fine after refreshing the same page (F5) without changing anything.

I try to find the cause but no success. That's the flow:

```
1. visit the page (index.php)
2. change the list (set: list_is_dirty = true)
3. click any internal link (call $(window).unload( ... save_data() ... )
4. target page appears without the list (syntax error!)
5. refreshing the page (everything works fine)
```

Do you have any idea how to find this error? Any tools or strategies? Or maybe the same experience with the unload function?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Some code:

```
var list_is_dirty = false;

// document ready?
$(function() {

    function sort_list() {
        // some code, not important
    }

    sort_list();

    $(window).unload(function() {
        if (list_is_dirty == true) {

            /* ---------- HERE's the error! ---------- */
            /* The error occures when I try to call the script.php 
               I tried load(), $.post(), $.get() but nothing works.
               The string is correct. I'm not even able to call any of 
               these functions without params. 
            */

            // send data to script.php to save data 
            $("#div").load("script.php?str="+list_data_str); 

            $.cookie("list_data", list_data_str);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit #2 / Solution:**
I don't know why, but everything works with window.onbeforeunload instead of jQuery.unload(). An explaination would be great! I'm sorry for this confusing thread!

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    $("#div").load("script.php");
}
```

Comment: Needs more actual code/errors, less paraphrasing.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for your reply. I try to figure out the important lines.

Comment: @aug I think you're on the right way. It's something like that I guess. I will post some code in a few minutes. Thanks!

Comment: How about posting all of the code, not *some code*? Errors would be nice, too.

Comment: @melpomene I would have to post too much code (company intern libraries). But I'm sure the error has anything to do with the unload function. The cookie changes without problems. I'm just not able to call another script in the unload-function. That's unfortunately the main problem. I found the error but not the solution. I hope it's okay for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue is with: list_data_str as it's not defined anywhere.
if you are trying to say that you want to do AJAX post for example, then obviously you need to look for success event
else it appears that what your demo code is missing something because you can do it the way you are trying if at the receiving script you use $_GET over the URL and not pay attention to any parameters.. In other words, you are missing the object and when you refresh the page it's loaded into the DOM. Apparently that could be the issue that you are describing, I would suggest that you post a bit more of relevant to your issue code.. like the receiving script or any errors from a debugger like Firebug.

Regarding how to test it, you might want to use console.log in supported browsers or simply alert when is setting up the cookie.

```
         var global list_is_dirty = false; 

              function sort_list(list, list_is_dirty) {
                // some code, not important
            //check the list and the flag 
            //you should return a value, else it does not make sense to use a function here.. note the var defined as global
            return list;  //?? not sure what to return as don't know what this code does from the posting
            }



              jQuery(function($)
              {

                $(window).load(function(e){

                                var list_data_str= sort_list( );


                        // send data to script.php to save data 
                        e("#div").load('script.php?str='+list_data_str); 

                                    //on unload destroy the cookie perhaps?? or if it's not set a session variable
                        e.cookie("list_data", list_data_str);

                ...


                            The unload event

                                $(window).unload(function(e) {


                              $("#div").load("script.php?str="+list_data_str); 

                                 $.cookie("list_data", list_data_str);
                                   }

                                });
                            }
                            ....
```

// About your EDIT: Are you passing in here any parameters to the script? Because I think the problem is at that logic.
                    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
                        $("#div").load("script.php");

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! The code wasn't working stand-alone, I just posted it to give you a rather overview. I got the idea to use window.onbeforeload from this page: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-unload

Comment: Interesting... I would love to see a demo if you can put it together in jsfiddle.. I believe that if you are trying to open a modal dialog window there are some other little details that you should consider. For example making it to have a unique ID to avoid multiple instances to be hidden, etc.. at that time perhaps if what you are looking for is to check if the dialog modal is unloaded that would make much more sense .. in the event that you are working with some processing, like submitting a form from the dialog window etc.. anyhow,  it's an interesting topic.